# Overrinding draw() in customized MapView in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Very simple question : since `MapView` inherits from `View`, is it possible to override `draw()` to draw whatever you want on the map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can use polylines, polygons, circles. If that's not enough you can put any bitmap (even one you draw to using Canvas) combined with ground overlay. If that's not enough, you can also use tile overlay to draw on entire map efficiently.

It's all there in the documentation, I encourage you to study.

Drawing directly can be always done on a view that overlaps with map, but it won't scroll with map nicely, so better to use technics above.

Drawing directly on the map is impossible, because it doesn't happen in your process afaik.